# QT Creator : Program crashes in debug mode but working in Release mode and in DEBUG Mode with breakpoints for QThread based program

Tags: c++, qt, debugging

I am working on a Desktop (Windows 7) based application and using Qt Creator v 5.6.0 for development of the Program.
I have a very strange issue i.e.

1. My Program crashes in DEBUG mode but works fine in RELEASE mode.
2. If in DEBUG mode, and I put break points to find the reason of the crash, then it doesn't crash: It work properly. But if I do not put any break points then it crashes at below code:

Project Background:
My Project includes functionality to read from the device connected at System communication port and transmits data to the MainWindow UI to display. Since to communicate with the communication port we have to use the third party library so I am not using QtSerial Port class which is much simpler and easy to use.

Code Design:
Class MainClass : In this class we have created some forms to display the data read from the device.

Class TestClass: This class will handle all the communication with the device connected at the system Serial Port and use the third party library. This class also have the while loop to read data from the device connected at Serial Port.

Since Test Class is using while loop. So we decided to make a Test Class run in different Thread.

Code for creating Thread in MainClass Constructor:

```
MainClass::MainClass (QWidget *parent) : QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Analzyer)
{
   ............................
   ............................

   workerThread = new QThread;
   testClassObject = new TestClass();   // Declared in HeaderFile of MainClass        

    if((workerThread != NULL) && (testClassObject != NULL))
    {
        workerThread ->moveToThread(testClassObject );

        connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(started()), testClassObject, SLOT(SomeFunc()));
        connect(testClassObject, SIGNAL(exit()), workerThread , SLOT(quit()));
        connect(testClassObject, SIGNAL(exit()), testClassObject,  SLOT(deleteLater()));
        connect(workerThread , SIGNAL(finished()), workerThread , SLOT(deleteLater()));

        // connectToPort Signal is emitted when User clicks the pushbutton from   // Main class UI
        connect(this, SIGNAL(connectToPort(QString)), testClassObject, SLOT(openPort(QString)));
    }

}
```

Crash Code:

```
void TestClass::openPort(const QString portName)
{
    // Here portName is say : "Appliance Interface v2"
    quint32 param2 = getParam2ForPortName(portName);
    qint16 portNumber = 0;

    QByteArray portNameByteArray = portName.toLatin1();

    const char *portNameToOpen = portNameByteArray.data();

     // Program crashed when return from this function
    if(func1(portNameToOpen , param2, 10 , &portNumber) == true)
    {
             ......................
             ......................
    }
}
```

Here, I added some qDebug() and found that my code crashes when it returns from or call the func1() which is getting called in slot OpenPort(). Below is the prototype of the func1()

```
bool func1 (const char portDescription[], uInt32 param2,
               uInt16 length, Int16 * portNr);
```

Since, func1() is the part of the library code. So I can not check the defination of the function func1(). I can assure that there is no problem in func1() Since it is being used in different java based projects and it works.

I did some more debugging on the Project and noticed that when in Run in DEBUG Mode with BreakPoints than in the QT Thread Debug Window I can see my connected Slot  but when I do not put any breakPoint than my code crashes and in Qt Thread Debug Window I can not see my connected Slot

So, It looks the problem of connection between the Main Class and the Test Class for openPort Slot.

But I am not able to understand taht when i put breakpoints in operPort() function than I can see my openPort Slot in Qt Thread Debug window but when no breakpoints than openPort Slot is not visible in Qt Thread Debug Window and Program Crashes.

Kindly Suggest,

Comment: Run the binary in a debugger, but without any breakpoints set. What's the exact line of the crash and the reason (debugger message)?

Comment: Hello All, I am able to solve the crash in Qt DEBUG mode without breakpoints if i use the DirectConnection Type like below          connect(this, SIGNAL(connectToPort(QString)), testClassObject, SLOT(openPort(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);  but still not able to understand what gets changed in Qt DEBUG mode with BreakPoints (when it does not crash) and in RELEASE mode (When it does not crash) with out using Qt::DirectConnection type?? Please suggest.

Comment: Since, I do not know that exact reason why It is not working without Qt::DirectConnection in DEBUG mode without breakpoints and working in DEBUG mode with breakpoints and in RELASE mode. So I am unable to answer this question and mark it as close.

Answer (score 0):

> I can assure that there is no problem in func1() Since it is being used in different java based projects and it works.

Wait, is func1() C++ or Java ?
Also, how can you be sure it works ?
Get the library source, compile it yourself, and debug in it.
And, just to be sure, check values of your variables while debugging, and qDebug() them when not debugging

Comment: this should be a comment rather than an answer, see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette).

Comment: I think it's better as an answer, the error is probably in one of his variables or the func1() function

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  func1() is declared in *.h header file for the library which I am using. I can say that func1() is working because same library with this header file is used in another desktop application but that is in Java. There it works properly. If i add a breakpoint than code works properly. I added qDebug() and noticed that qDebug() inside func1() and at return of  openPort() func was not visible. Only before func1() was visible to find out the crash point.

Comment: I guess it's cross-platform then, and I don't know so much in cross platform -- maybe it's working in Java but not in C++. Where did you exactly add the qDebug ? In the if statement, after the if, or before ?

Comment: @Mike: I see you edited your message to add the link, but I also hadn't enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @RandomCoder99: I added qDebug() like below:                                                                                    qDebug() << "Before calling func1"; // This qDebugu() is visible. if(func1(portNameToOpen , param2, 10 , &portNumber) == true)
    {                                                                                                                        qDebug() << "Inside If()";  //Not Visible
.....

    }                                                                                                                       qDebug() << "OutSide if()" ;  //Not Visible

Comment: qDebug() your variables, and assert your pointers to see if everything is alright. (Do this before the if statement)

Comment: @RandomCoder99 , when I posted my message your reputation was 75 and this is enough to comment. anyway congrats for your reputation. Personally, I think that any thing that is asking the OP for a reply should be a comment rather than an answer :)

Comment: @Mike When I posted my answer, I only had 36 reputation, but now I have enough to comment, thanks

Comment: Hello All, I have modified the query since it was not usefull and incomplete. I will take care while posting a query from next time. Since, I am beginner. So i did this mistakes.

Comment: Okay so, first, remove the "if((workerThread != NULL) && (testClassObject != NULL))" or use an assert instead. Then, Use the [new signal/slot connect syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) to see if there's any error from here. And can you give the new code with asserts and qDebugs ?

Comment: Just for updates: I am able to solve the crash in Qt DEBUG mode without breakpoints if i use the DirectConnection Type while connecting SIGNALS like below connect(this, SIGNAL(connectToPort(QString)), testClassObject, SLOT(openPort(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);  With "Qt::DirectConnection" code is working in all scenarios.  But I am not able to understand the reason why code was crashing in DEBUG mode without breakpoints and not crashing in RELEASE as well as DEBUG mode with breakpoints and how "DirectConnection" help to solve all this issue.

Comment: Seems when using Qt::DirectConnection it works, but not with Qt::QueuedConnection. (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html) Try using Qt::QueuedConnection instead of the default or Direct, and tell me if it crashes

Comment: @RandomCoder99: If i use Qt::QueuedConnection than it crashes but not wirh Qt::DirectConnections

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for replying on my own post but after lots of dicussion on StackOverflow and google. I was able to solve the Issue.

To Solve the Issue:
I changed the SLOT(openPort) as mentioned below:

```
Connect(this, SIGNAL(connectToPort(QString)), testClassObject, SLOT(openPort(QString)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

That is to use the "Qt:DirectConnection" method. If we don't specify a connection method, the direct method is automatically used for connections between objects on the SAME thread. 
Since here we have created a new QThread for TestClass and using a thirdParty library which might not be a thread safe.
So using "Qt::DirectConnection" make the openPort() SlOT to run in MainClass Thread. Basically, it's as if emitting the signal calls the slot method "directly".